# Can that kind of application can be done? There

Tags: iphone

I have an idea for really effective internet ad. Is it possible to write some cellphone application (hide in game or something) that downloads name or ringtone file of the logged user of some internet service. The idea of effective internet ad (like a flash banner) will be the sound of the advertise. It will play user cellphone ringtone as a background to wake up feeling that he is needed for something and useful. Like a Pavlovs reflex.

Is it too much "big brother thing" ?

(sorry about english)

Comment: there's no way to find out the user's ringtone with the public API

Answer (score 3):

Extremely intrusive and would be very annoying. People do not want sound when they're browsing unless they choose to hear it.